# Expression `t => (t.SomeProperty As Object)` refers to a method, not a property

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I have created this expression in some code:

```
t => (t.SomeProperty As Object)
```

and now I'm trying to get the property-name (`SomeProperty`) by this little snippet (got from Internet a long time ego):

```
    public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TSource, TProperty>
        (TSource source, Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertyLambda) {
        var type = typeof(TSource);

        var member = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member == null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{propertyLambda}' refers to a method, not a property.");

        var propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{propertyLambda}' refers to a field, not a property.");

        if (type != propInfo.ReflectedType && !type.IsSubclassOf(propInfo.ReflectedType))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Expresion '{propertyLambda}' refers to a property that is not from type {type}.");

        return propInfo;
    }
```

But as you know, `propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression` is always null, cause this: `t => (t.Some1 As Object)` is not a property-refer. Is there any way to get the property-name in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# `as` operator translates to [`Expression.TypeAs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.typeas(v=vs.110).aspx), and C# cast operators translate to either [`Expression.Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Expression.ConvertChecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.convertchecked(v=vs.110).aspx). As you can see, all they are of type [`UnaryExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.unaryexpression(v=vs.110).aspx), hence you can extract the operand expression by using [`Operand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.unaryexpression.operand(v=vs.110).aspx) property. And you can do that in a loop in order to support multiple casts.

Putting it into action, replace

```
var member = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
```

with

```
var operand = propertyLambda.Body;
while (operand.NodeType == ExpressionType.TypeAs || operand.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert || operand.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked)
    operand = ((UnaryExpression)operand).Operand;
var member = operand as MemberExpression;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you need to look at the operand of the unary expression that is the cast.

```
((propertyLamdba.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MemberExpression).Member
```

To make it more programmatically secure, you should check your propertyLamba.
Something like:

```
if (propertyLamdba.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.TypeAs)
    member = ((propertyLamdba.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MemberExpression).Member
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this:

```
PropertyInfo info = t.GetType().GetProperty("SomeProperty",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
// Use these binding flags to get a member of any visibility.
```

It returns a `PropertyInfo` for a property of a given name.

If you do not want to handle the name explicitly, use `nameof(t.SomeProperty)`.

You may also find the method `.GetProperties` useful to get all properties of a specific type.